# Where are my GO Binaries going?

Tags: go

Installed go according to the documents on the site. Set GOPATH to ~/go. My bin directory is empty when I try to run "go install" on an application. There is no error message, which leads me to believe that their was no errors and everything compiled correctly. How do I find out where the binaries are being put?

**Update:**

Typing in `go env` give me this:

`GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/Users/kkaske/go/bin"
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/kkaske/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
TERM="dumb"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"`

Comment: Have a look to [Go's Code Organization](http://golang.org/doc/code.html#Organization).

Comment: Pass `-x` to `go install` to see what it's doing.  A sheer guess is that while you have "set" `GOPATH` you haven't *exported* it and that's why `go` tools don't "see" it (and hence don't use it).

Comment: My GOPATH is set and exported in my .bash_profile. When I add -x to go install it outputs something like "WORK=/var/folders/d6/k0j3vmv548q7hhkdln911rr5mt824g/T/go-build563586624"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***VERY SIMPLE SOLUTION:***

**My fix works on Ubuntu based systems.**

First we have to setup the Workspace for you where you can start working on your Go Projects.

Note: I am using directory names which I have used on my system to configure Go. You can use your own directory names.

Step 1:
Create a directory named **GoLang**

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/GoLang
```

Now move into GoLang Directory.

```
$ cd $HOME/GoLang
```

Step 2:
Create two directories named **"bin"** and  **"src"** inside GoLang directory.

```
$ mkdir -p bin
$ mkdir -p src
```

**Extra Info: src directory contains source files with .go extension and bin directory contains executable files.**

Step 3:
Now we have to edit your ***.bashrc*** file.

Type this command in the Terminal.

```
$ nano ~/.bashrc
```

.bashrc file will open and you have to scroll down to the end and type these lines.

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/GoLang/src
export GOBIN=$HOME/GoLang/bin
```

Final step is to save the file and restart the terminal.

Now run `go env` and you will see something like this:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/home/infoir/GoLang/bin"
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/infoir/GoLang/src"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
TERM="dumb"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Answer (score 4):

Just run "go env"
and you will get something like this:
    GOARCH="amd64"
    GOBIN=""
    GOCHAR="6"
    GOEXE=""
    GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
    GOHOSTOS="linux"
    GOOS="linux"
    GOPATH="/home/laz10049/go/"
    GORACE=""
    GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
    GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
    CC="gcc"
    GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
    CGO_ENABLED="1"

So in my case binaries will be located at "/usr/local/go/bin" ($GOROOT + "/bin/")

Answer (score 3):

is your applications source within your gopath?

It should be in $GOPATH/src/yourpath - using symlinks here is very useful. Then it will be published to the relative $GOPATH/bin location :)

Comment: Yes. My $GOPATH is set to $HOME/go and this application is downloaded to $GOPATH/src/github.com/username/projectname/